# How to play individual track number from playlist at start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, jplayer

I am using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org) plugin. Here is an example [link [ jsfiddle ]](http://bit.ly/1dSDZxH). I just want to start playlist from an individual track number, i mean if i have 5/10 tracks in a playlist then i want to start playlist from 2/5 track number at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify a bit the `play()` method in order to randomly selects the song to play.

Find below the code and this is an update to your [fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/f05wxf1e/8/)

```
var myPlayer = new jPlayerPlaylist( /* give your params here as you were doing */);

// Clonning current play() method behavior
myPlayer._play = myPlayer.play;

// Modifying default behavior of current play() method which generates
// a random song index if not provided
myPlayer.play = function(songIdx){

    if (!songIdx)
        songIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.playlist.length);

    this._play(songIdx);

    console.log('Playing song #', songIdx);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro excellent but can i add manually a number of track? @leo.fcx

Comment: Yes it is! ... see this updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/f05wxf1e/9/) ... if this was helpful please up-vote.

Comment: Ok then i up-vote but i want to add manual track number without Math.floor/songIdx function please update @leo.fcx

Comment: The last jsfiddle that I provided (in previous comment) already has that change ... were you able to try it?

Comment: yes but 1 problem is when i want to play 1 and click 2 time on botton then it play last one or randomly tracks

Comment: Oh I saw it ... please try this new one (http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/f05wxf1e/10/) ... that was an edge case

Comment: Hi can you solve this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365538/how-to-save-current-playing-song-in-cookie @leo.fcx