# How to save current playing song in cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, cookies, jplayer

I am using jPlayer plugin. Here is an example [link [ jsfiddle ]](http://bit.ly/1JXXR0S).

I save the current playing track number in a cookie. After a browser reload it starts playing from the track number loaded from the cookie. This works but the problem is, after the current track ends, it starts to play from the first track of the playlist. I want it to continue to the next track.

**Example of current situation:**

- playlist have 10 songs
- clicked on number 3 song
- cookie saved number 3 song
- browser reload
- start playing number 3 song from playlist
- number 3 song ends
- **start playing from number 1 song**

**Desired situation:**

- playlist have 10 songs
- clicked on number 3 song
- cookie saved number 3 song
- browser reload
- start playing number 3 song from playlist
- number 3 song ends
- **start playing number 4 song**
- number 4 song ends
- start playing number 5 song
- ...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you understand now? @alan0xd7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myPlayer.play()` expects an `integer` value, but when you read from the cookie you get a `string`. So to fix your problem, just pass the value through `parseInt()`, like this:

```
myPlayer.play(parseInt(playnow));
```

You will notice that on page reload, the proper track will be selected in the playlist as it starts playing, and it will continue to the next track correctly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/6kx616hr/1/

By the way, I think `setInterval` with `1` (1 millisecond) is too much, maybe `1000` (1 second) is enough.

Comment: Thanks bro but i want to know what is parseInt()? please vote-up if you did vote-down i have no score to ask any question next... @alan0xd7

Comment: `parseInt()` converts the value into an `integer`, it is a different data type. An `integer` is a number, while a `string` is a series of letters.

Comment: For example: `var a = "1";` and `var b = 1;`, here `a` is a `string` (notice the quotes), and `b` is an `integer`, and `a != b`

Comment: Read more about [JavaScript data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: I did not. Maybe next time you could write your question better, so it is more readable.